# How can I turn DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection into the closest CodeElement in a VS2008 Macro?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-macros, envdte

I'm working with the Visual Studio 2008 object model as seen here: [VS2008 Automation Object Model Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/za2b25t3.aspx).

I want to act on a `CodeElement` in a VS2008 Marco, one that is chosen by the user's text selection in the current .cs document.

While I don't really care how I get it, this is what I tried: The VS object model gives you `DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection` which is of type `TextSelection`, and then there is the `DTE.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.FileCodeModel.CodeElementFromPoint()` method which takes a `TextPoint` and `vsCMEElement` as parameters and returns the `CodeElment` like I want.

However I can't seem to get a `TextElement` from a `TextSelection`.

Can someone tell me how to get a `CodeElement` from the selected text in a .cs file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

textSelection = DTE.ActiveWindow.Selection

codeElement = textSelection.ActivePoint.CodeElement(vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass)